# Axios get request inside useEffect gives infinite loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, use-effect, mern

Calling axios get request inside useEffect results in infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
    get();
});

const get = async () => {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/events/get").then((res) => {
        setEvents(res.data);
    });
    console.log(events);
};
```

[image]

but if i give dependency as second argument, then only empty array is returned 2 times.

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    get();
}, []);

const get = async () => {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/events/get").then((res) => {
        setEvents(res.data);
    });
    console.log(events);
};
```

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: @krishnkumarmodanval its still the same

Comment: The problem is in the way `setEvent` and `events` mutation propagate. You need to `React` to changes. As in @melvin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook `useState()` returns a function to mutate the state, in this case `setEvents`. This mutation function is **asynchronous** in nature meaning the state does not update immediately as it waits for the component to re-render.

When calling `console.log` statement right after the `setEvents` method, it will print out an outdated copy of the `events` state and thus you see the empty array.

In order to confirm if your network request properly works, try logging the value of `events` in a separate `useEffect` hook with `events` as the dependency. This will run that useEffect block as soon as `events` state updates after a re-render:

```
// Make the network request
useEffect(() => {
    get();
}, []);

// Check if the events state updated
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(events);  // Move the console log here
}, [events]);             // Add `events` as a dependency

const get = async () => {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/events/get").then((res) => {
        setEvents(res.data);
    });
    console.log(events);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are using React 18. In new React 18 for adding some new functionality in future they have designed such that in strict mode useEffect will run twice. You can either stop running the app in strict mode or [Follow this one](https://dev.to/ag-grid/react-18-avoiding-use-effect-getting-called-twice-4i9e).

Another Option [Here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-18-useeffect-double-call-for-apis-emergency-fix-724b7ee6a646)

And as you mentioned about the dependency array, so you must be knowing how to avoid the infinite execution

Answer (score 0):

Before coming to any solutions I would like to suggest two chores in order to debug the problem.

### Using try-catch block to catch any errors in the api itself

```js
const get = async () => {
try{
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/events/get").then((res) => {
        setEvents(res.data);
    });
    console.log(events);
} catch (e){
console.error(e)
}
};
```

### Try defining the get() function inside the useEffect()

```js
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const get = async () => {
try{
    await axios.get("http://localhost:5001/events/get").then((res) => {
        setEvents(res.data);
    });
    console.log(events);
} catch (e){
console.error(e)
}
};
 get();
}, []);
```

You may share yout findings after doing that and it may help us in debugging the probllem.

Thank you!!!